# How can I make a basic text clock in Visual C++ Windows Form

Tags: visual-studio-2008, visual-c++

as the title says, is there a way I can have a clock that updates every minute the time from the machine

Eg, a text that says "The time is 5.04pm"

then a minute later

"The time is 5.05pm"

Comment: Are you looking at a GUI or console clock?

Comment: its for a gui, a windows form

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could start a thread (separate from the GUI thread) that sleeps for a minute, wakes up and updates the GUI textbox value.

Comment: Cool, I just had a look at that, I added

Comment: SYSTEMTIME SystemTime;
GetSystemTime(&SystemTime);   Now i just need to figure out how to convert to a String for the Label

Comment: You can manually extract fields. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms724950%28VS.85%29.aspx